# NavigationLink in Angular

Tags: swiftui-navigationlink

configurationLink: string[] = [
'camp-dashboard/step1-form-page',
'camp-dashboard/step2-form-page',
];

new NavigationLink('Configuration', ["my url"], 'settings')
above this Navigation Link is the url is came in dynamically and the url is multple came. so how to solve this problem and i already tried using configurationLink array.but two url in this array but the navigation link is picked one url another url is not picked.why?in angular

i expected one NavigationLink multiple url binding